# How to iterate all S3 Buckets in an account across regions

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to iterate and retrieve the policies about all S3 buckets in an account.

I am trying the following...

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
buckets = s3.list_buckets()
for bucket_name in buckets['Buckets']:
    s3.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name['Name'])
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
 botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (PermanentRedirect) when calling the GetBucketTagging operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

I've tried used `s3.meta.client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name['Name'])` as per https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/81, but I get a value of `None` for `'LocationConstraint'`.

How can I know or ascertain the correct endpoint and/or region for an arbitrary bucket?

Comment: within the for loop, you do s3.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket['Name'])...so bucket_name isnt being used...are you sure it shouldn't use bucket_name (some kind of typo?)

Comment: Oops, yes I had a typo!

Comment: i think u need one more edit from bucket[..] to bucket_name[...] in the line ..."i've tried used"...also , thats not the cause of your issues?

Comment: I think I have them all now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, minus one tidbit: a value of `None` indicates US Standard region [[1]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html#RESTBucketGETlocation-responses-response-elements), or `us-east-1`. Also, you do not need to use the meta client. The client you've already created has the [`get_bucket_location`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_location) method.